# Difference between isExternalStorageRemovable and isExternalStorageEmulated

Tags: android

`Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()` was added in API 9

And `Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated()` was added in API 11

`isExternalStorageRemovable` returns true when `getExternalStorageDirectory`'s path is removable or not, more like a SD Card and if it return false, its internal storage and can never be removed physically.

And `isExternalStorageEmulated` is just do opposite of `isExternalStorageRemovable` ?

Now, my question is whats the difference ? Is it just different name with opposite output ?

Answer (score 6):

`isExternalStorageEmulated() == true` means that there is no real SD card and it is just emulated (Nexus 5 for example). if the external storage isn't emulated `isExternalStorageEmulated() == false` then it can either be removable or not that is why we have `isExternalStorageRemovable()`

Comment: Cant we simply use `isExternalStorageRemovable` to determine if `getExternalStorageDirectory` is SDCard or not ?

Comment: @xmenW.K. isExternalStorageRemovable can help you determine if the external storage is removable or not (it can be false and yet the device has an sdcard).

Comment: `isExternalStorageEmulated` returns true in sony xperia ZR and it has sdcard too. But its primary storage is internal. Seems to me that its just opposite of `isExternalStorageRemovable`

Comment: I think the xperia ZR considers the internal storage as an emulated SD card and the removable as a second SD card. does it make sense to you?

Comment: Doesn't make much sense but why they had to make it that difficult and not reliable.

Comment: doesn't it all mean that isExternalStorageEmulated()== !isExternalStorageRemovable() , for all cases? also, what should be done for previous APIs ?

Comment: I have a 4.2.1 device here which returns isExternalStorageEmulated()==false and isExternalStorageRemovable()==false (?)

Comment: It is possible for a device to have a non-removable microSD card, which is used as "external" storage. In this case, isExternalStorageEmulated() and isExternalStorageRemovable() can both return false. But AFAIK, you cannot have both return true. Remember that "external" is a technical term that doesn't mean "removable". @android

Comment: 'Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be mounted as a filesystem on a computer.' http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: @LarsH I don't understand the case of both being false.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: I don't understand it very well either. The docs for is...Emulated() say "If true, data stored on this device will be stored on a portion of the internal storage system." So for the case of both being false, I guess the external storage must not be on the "internal storage system" but could be on a built-in non-removable microSD card?

Comment: @LarsH But if it's in a "built-in non-removable microSD card", it's emulated, I think.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: Why? Emulated as what? The docs are not clear in regard to what being emulated means. I guess we can infer that it's the *external* aspect that's emulated, which means that emulated external storage is not physically external under the hood. To make sense of that, I'd guess that in the "both false" case, the built-in non-removable microSD card **is** considered external under the hood, in the sense that it's not part of the main internal flash storage. So in that sense it's not emulated. But I'm just guessing, and I don't know why isEmulated() would be useful to know.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: A little more insight is provided here: https://source.android.com/devices/storage/index.html "Android supports devices with external storage, which is defined to be a case-insensitive filesystem with immutable POSIX permission classes and modes. External storage can be provided by physical media (such as an SD card), or by exposing a portion of internal storage through an emulation layer." So a built-in SD card, being "physical media", and providing a case-insensitive FS (e.g. FAT32), *really is* external storage by this definition, not emulated.

Comment: @LarsH Do you know of such a thing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82343/discussion-between-larsh-and-android-developer).

Answer (score 0):

From the Android documentation:

`isExternalStorageEmulated`

> Returns whether the primary shared/external storage media is emulated.

`isExternalStorageRemovable`

> Returns whether the primary shared/external storage media is physically removable.

Meaning that both can, in some ways, tell you the same thing.

> The contents of emulated storage devices are backed by a private user data partition

API 21 also supports a path parameter rather than assuming primary external storage, but the documentation is nearly identical for the logic behind the usage of both methods.

In practical terms, it may come down to which will invert your condition, what API you choose to target, or if a physical sdcard is somehow relevant to your usage (ie. Samsung devices with both removable and emulated storage).